# Passe Image through intent

Tags: java, android, xml, android-intent, android-glide

In my **first activity** , I load an **image** with **glide**

```
 Glide.with(getBaseContext())
      .load(image)
      .asBitmap()
      .into(new SimpleTarget<Bitmap>(myWidth, myHeight) {
          @Override
          public void onResourceReady(Bitmap resource, GlideAnimation<? super Bitmap> glideAnimation) {
              content_image.setImageBitmap(resource);
          }
      });
```

now I want to show the same **image** in another `activity` with a full screen `imageView`..

This is the code I wrote in my **first activity**

```
public void openPoster(View v){
    Toast.makeText(this,"Click sur l'image", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    Intent i =new Intent(this, Affiche.class);
    Bitmap bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable)content_image.getDrawable()).getBitmap();
    i.putExtra("imageBitmap", bitmap);
    startActivity(i);
}
```

and now in the **second activity**

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
Bitmap bmp = intent.getParcelableExtra("imageBitmap");
img.setImageBitmap(bmp);
```

Comment: And your code looks OK what is your problem?

Comment: and the issue would be???

Comment: What is the problem?? Are you getting any eorror??

Comment: the second activity does not start. My manifest file is ok. When i put just the intent second activity launch, when i pass the bitmap in the image, nothing. :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Intent has not documented limit for data, so do not send bitmap like that. Glide uses LRU cache, that means next time you'll request the image by URL you'll receive it from the cache, so just send the image URL via intent